# Cloudformation root stack resources are not split properly with serverless-plugin-split-stacks

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless, serverless-plugins

We use `serverless-plugin-split-stacks` to break resources into nested stacks and have set it up in `serverless.yml` as follows.

```
custom:
  splitStacks:
    perFunction: false
    perType: true
    perGroupFunction: false
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: ./webpack.config.js
    includeModules: true
```

Everything was going well until we were greeted with the following error

> Error: The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template format error: Number of resources, 206, is > greater than maximum allowed, 200

When this error happens, the condition of the nested stacks is as follows.

```
Serverless: [serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    Resources per stack:
Serverless: [serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    - (root): 206
Serverless: [serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    - APINestedStack: 55
Serverless: [serverless-plugin-split-stacks]:    - PermissionsNestedStack: 49
```

My problem is that **even though we have set up split-stacks properly, why doesn't it split the resources in the root stack into new stacks?**

If there's anything I have missed here, please educate me on this. Thanks for all helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This npm package **serverless-plugin-split-stacks** not working. This package has been **Deprecated - FAILED - BUG**
For more information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-split-stacks

To resolve your problem (Serverless Workarounds for CloudFormation's 200 Resource Limit) read some tips:
https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-workaround-cloudformation-200-resource-limit

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @vanderson-andrade. However, recently we removed this plugin from our project as AWS raised the resources limit in a CloudFormation stack and bugs started to appear from the `split-stacks` plugin. Therefore this problem mentioned in the question no longer occurs.

Comment: @Pavindu if you are not using this plugin which one you are currently using it then?